# Exchange colors to grey scale (height map)

Tags: colors, exchange, gimp

I found this highres moon height map. 
http://lroc.sese.asu.edu/posts/451

Sorry, you need to scroll down then theres the image with the scale. **It's the last image before the scale.**

However 3D software needs greyscale values for height information. How can I convert this color height map to an accurate grey scale height map with like gimp or krita? I tried gimp colors -> map -> exchange color but it only changes one exact value not a range.

Comment: Did you try using the Hue-Saturation tool to decrease saturation?

Comment: No that wouldnt work, please look at the scale there are bright colors in the middle, height information would be wrong. It need that black = lowest and white = highest.

Comment: Which image are you referring to? There are at least 5 on that page.

Comment: You might have some success in Gimp using Colors -> Curves and then fiddling with the individual color channels, but since they seem to have used violet at the low end of the scale it doesn't quite map right like this... basically you'd need a tool where you could define a mapping from (R,G,B) to single channel values, but I'm not able to refer to you anything useful right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the time to test it but I think this should work:

In the GIMP Palette Editor (`Windows > Dockable > Palettes`), create a copy of the `Grays (32)` palette, and replace the colors with ones selected from the height legend image, trying to get an even spacing across the spectrum and overwriting dark to light with low (purple/blue) to high (red/white).

Open the heightmap image, select `Image > Mode > Indexed` and select your new palette. Dithering might help depending on what you're using this for.

Select the Gray palette, then `Colors > Map > Palette Map`. Should replace the colors one-to-one.

Edit: It might be quicker and more accurate (more than 32 colors) to `Import Palette` from gradient and attempt to recreate the gradient they used. Then import from gradient a grayscale palette using the same number of colors.